# Why does the following piece of code give this error ? The number of parameters required is 2, yet 1 parameter is asked?

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
l=[]
class employee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__reg_no=input("Enter registration number:")
        self.__desig=raw_input("Enter designation:")
        self.__sal=input("Enter salary:")
        self.name=raw_input("Enter name:")

    def disp(self):            
        print   "Name                           :",self.name
        print  "Registration number  :",self.__reg_no
        print  "Designation                 :",self.__desig
        print  "Salary                            :",self.__sal

    def __getattr__(self):
        x=raw_input("Enter name of employee who's profile you want to access:")
        y=input("Enter registration number:")
        for i in l:
            if x==getattr(i,'name'):
                if y==getattr(i,'reg_no'):
                    i.disp()


n=input("Enter number of employees:")

for i in range(n):
    ob=employee()
    l.append(ob)
    if i==n-1:
        print "Enter 1 to view everyone's profile."
        print "Enter 2 to view a specific emplyees detail."
        a1=input("Enter your option here:")
        if a1==1:
            for o in l:
                o.disp()

        elif a1==2:
            for o in l:
                o.__getattr__()
```

And this is what the error says during runtime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Prajesh_2\Desktop\test.py", line 43, in <module>
    o.__getattr__()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Prajesh_2\Desktop\test.py", line 24, in __getattr__
    if y==getattr(i,'reg_no'):
TypeError: __getattr__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `__getattr__` implementation only *accepts* one argument, `self`, but it is *given* `self` and the name of the attribute. Because your `employee` class has no `reg_no` attribute (not with that spelling), `getattr(i, 'reg_no')` triggers a `i.__getattr__('reg_no')` call automatically to try and find the missing attribute by other means.

The proper way to implement `__getattr__` is to have it accept the name of the attribute to fetch; do **not** ask for the name using `input()`; that is the work of the code using `getattr()` elsewhere.

It looks like you really want to use a *different name* for the method here; you are not properly implementing the hook, nor do you need to here.

You don't need to use `getattr()` either; you are not using dynamic attribute names, you could just directly access `_employe__reg_no` and `name`:

```
def search(self):
    x=raw_input("Enter name of employee who's profile you want to access:")
    y=input("Enter registration number:")
    for i in l:
        if x == i.name':
            if y == i._employee__reg_no:
                i.disp()
```

and use `o.search()` rather than `o.__getattr__()`.

Note that I had to use the attribute `_employee__reg_no` there because you used a double underscore on the `__reg_no` attribute! Don't use double underscores on attribute names unless you need to protect those attributes from accidental re-use in subclasses.